# How to write formula to get this result in excel

Tags: excel

Please refer the below screenshot:

[image]

I have 4 users on this sheet (User1, User2, User3 and User4) and a User's Catalog that shows a date in front of each user. Now what I want is to display the max date for each user in row 3 under their respective Names, so that the result is something like this:

[image]

Any Idea how to write a formula to achieve this result?

P.S. I know I have to try it first, but I a complete newbie to excel and don't know much except for very basic formula. For this one, I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this array formula.

```
=MAX(IF($A$6:$A$15=A$2,$B$6:$B$15,""))
```

[image]

Make sure you enter it as an array formula. So, you have to press ***CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER*** after putting formula in cell.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I thought of using the MAXIFS at first suggested in the other answer but mine version of Excel didn't supported it. Since this works on previous versions of EXCEL without any hickups this is the suitable answer for this question. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have another question on excel .. I think you are the perfect candidate to answer that as well .. It will be a great help to me ... here's the question :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086256/how-to-write-the-formula-to-make-this-happen-in-excel

Comment: Can you share a sample workbook via google drive and put link here. Otherwise I have to type it manually. I know the answer of your question.

Comment: Sure .. just give me a minute :)

Comment: Here's the link to the file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dRkQMZgWdDEjQGocvlvWtZxbiQH2dG65/view?usp=sharing

Comment: See the answer on that post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MAXIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883). In cell A3, put:

```
=MAXIFS($B$6:$B$14, $A$6:$A$14, "="&A2)
```

You can then drag copy that across into B3, C3 and D3.

Comment: I think this one is easier to use, but unfortunately mine version for excel do not support this :(

Comment: Bummer! Which version are you using? Happy to see the other answer could work in your version though.

Comment: Using Excel 2016 .. but still can't see the MAXIFS function :( ... Thanks for your answer anyway .. I will see if I can update my Excel version to use this formula :)

Comment: Btw .. I have another problem in excel which I need help for .. would you mind looking at this question for me :) .. it would be a great help to me :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086256/how-to-write-the-formula-to-make-this-happen-in-excel

Comment: Just looked at the help on MAXIFS again - it's in 2016 but **only** if you are using it through an Office 365 subscription. So I guess I got lucky. Anyway, I'll take a look at your other question.

Comment: I am not using it through office 365 :( but thanks for giving me an update on this Nick :) .. I will be waiting for your answer on my another question :) Thanks :)