# How to write the formula to make this happen in Excel

Tags: excel

Please refer the below screenshot:

[image]

Assume that today's date is **29-4-2018** (*dd-mm-yyyy*). There are two users (*User 1* and *User 2*). Both of them have worked in various Workspaces (*Workspace1*, *Workspace 2* and *Workspace 3*) on different dates.

I want to calculate the number of jobs a user has done on today's date in various workspaces and then display the count in cell C2 and C3 respectively so that the result is something like this:

[image]

Any Idea how to write a formula to achieve this result?

P.S. I know I have to try it first, but I a complete newbie to excel and don't know much except for very basic formula. For this one, I don't even know where to start.

EDIT:
Just in case if anyone wants to [download this workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dRkQMZgWdDEjQGocvlvWtZxbiQH2dG65/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is a programming site (see [help/on-topic]) - for specific programming issues (not a formula writing service or a place to learn the very basic of programming)  I'd suggest sites [like this one to get you started](https://www.lifewire.com/excel-formulas-step-by-step-tutorial-3123636)  or more [here](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&q=beginner+excel+formulas). Also refer to superuser.com. Good luck!

Comment: Consider redesigning your worksheet to be just four columns - one added for Workspace. With this normalized data you could use pivot tables and easier formulas.

Comment: Hi Glancy :) Actually, this sheet is a simplified version of another complex sheet in which the columns cannot be changed due to some reasons. To reduce the complexity of the question and to make it easier to understand I redesigned the sheet into a simpler one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula in `C2` cell

```
=COUNTIFS($B$8:$B$26,B2,$D$8:$D$26,"29-04-2018")+COUNTIFS($E$8:$E$26,B2,$G$8:$G$26,"29-04-2018")+COUNTIFS($H$8:$H$26,B2,$J$8:$J$26,"29-04-2018")
```

If it is actually today then you can replace `29-04-2018` with `Today()` so, the formula will be

```
=COUNTIFS($B$8:$B$26,B2,$D$8:$D$26,TODAY())+COUNTIFS($E$8:$E$26,B2,$G$8:$G$26,TODAY())+COUNTIFS($H$8:$H$26,B2,$J$8:$J$26,TODAY())
```

## Edited answer from Scott Craner comments

```
=COUNTIFS($B$8:$H$26,B2,$D$8:$J$26,TODAY())
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :) .. it works .. just a little problem .. actually the number of workspaces can increase .. or should I just say the number of workspaces are anywhere between 25 - 30 ... is there a more smart formula that can be written if number of workspace increase or decreases .. so that we don't have to actually edit the formula everytime.

Comment: Sure there is, just use offset ranges of the same size: `=COUNTIFS($B$8:$H$26,B2,$D$8:$J$26,TODAY())`  As long as the ranges are the same size just offset two columns it will work. @KuldeepKumar

Comment: @ScottCraner I just uses formula by you in answer. It is for if other visitor come here then they can see the answer is useful.

Comment: Thanks Scott :) Your solution worked just fine for me :)

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for that - I hadn't realised `COUNTIFS` could be made to work that way.